# JDOM.Element.getChild(String) is returning unexpected results

Tags: java, jdom

According to the API at [jdom.org](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/Element.html#getChild(java.lang.String)), the semantics of `getChild(String name)`:

> This returns the first child element within this element with the given local name and belonging to no namespace. If no elements exist for the specified name and namespace, null is returned.

Therefore, if I have an XML structure like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lvl1>
    <lvl2>
        <lvl3/>
    </lvl2>
</lvl1>
```

I have a JDOM Element which is currently pointing to `<lvl1>`. I should be able to make the following call:

```
Element lvl3 = lvl1Element.getChild("lvl3");
```

and `lvl3` should have non-null.

**However**, I'm finding that `lvl3` is actually `null`.  Am I missing something?

Here is a sample code snippet that should work:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import org.jdom.*;
public static void main(String[] args){
    Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(new StringReader("path to file"));
    Element lvl1Element = doc.getRootElement();
    Element lvl3Element = lvl1Element.getChild("lvl3"); //is null. Why?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the functionality I was looking for, I used an `Iterator` from the `getDescendants(ElementFilter)` function from [jdom.org](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/Element.html#getDescendants%28org.jdom.filter.Filter%29)

I then got the `Element` I was looking for by using code similar to the following:

```
Element lvl3 = lvl1.getDescendants(new ElementFilter("lvl3"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You've just said it....

> This returns the first child element
>   within this element with the given
>   local name...

Basically, on `lvl1`, your first child is `lvl2`. I haven't used JDOM to help further. My suggestion is to go to `lvl2` and retrieve `lvl3`.

Comment: `lvl3` is **first** child of `lvl2`, not `lvl1`. `lvl2` is first child of `lvl1`.

Comment: It appears that our definitions of the term "child" are different.  I understand "child" to mean "descendant" (which is more general), but your definition seems to describe the reason why I am experiencing this behavior.  I understood "descendant" to be the correct understanding because in another function in the API <A HREF="http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/Element.html#getChildren()" > getChildren </A>, it specifies only the *first* level as children.  Since `getChild(String)` was missing that distinction, I thought it meant any *descendant*.

Comment: The `getChildren()` returns only the children of the element and not grand children. I wouldn't know how you would get grand children on JDOM though. Why not use `element.getElementsByTagName()` method (if that exists in JDOM)?

Comment: I do not think that `getElementsByTagName()` exists in JDOM (AFAIK, that is a DOM method).  To get my intended behavior, I'm using the `getDescendants(ElementFilter)` function, which does what `getElementsByTagName()` does.

Comment: @David, then you're sorted. :)

Answer (score 0):

> ---lvl1

```
---lvl2(child of lvl1)

  ---lvl3(child of lvl2)
```

Comment: But `lvl3` *is still* a child of `lvl1.`

Comment: "In the DOM, there is no concept of “grandparents” or anything like that, so you will need to access elements one level at a time." Taken from http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/an-introduction-to-the-dom